# Converting a JSON file of unknown structure to CSV using R

Tags: json, r, csv

I am looking for a way to convert a rather big (3GB) json file to csv.  I tried using R and this is the code that I used.

```
library("rjson")
data <- fromJSON(file="C:/POI data 30 Rows.json")
json_data <- as.data.frame(data)
write.csv(json_data, file='C:/POI data 30 Rows Exported.csv')
```

The example I am using is only a subset of the total data of about 30 rows. which I extracted using EMeditor and copied and pasted into a text file. The problem is however it only converts the first row of the data.

I am not an experienced programmer and have tried everything on youtube tutorials from php to excel and nothing seems to work.  The problem is I have no Idea what the structure of the data is so I can not create a predetermined data frame and there is a number of missing values within the data.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you paste some of the content of the `.json` file in your question?

Comment: Or a link to the JSON would be helpful also

Comment: Here is the link to the data set:https://www.kaggle.com/jboysen/uk-psc/data